# Resistive force proportional to velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, drag

> Find the displacement and velocity of horizontal motion in a medium in which the retarding force is proportional to the velocity.

I kind of understand how to do this problem.

We know that the resistive force $F_r \propto v$. Since $F_r$ is the only force present in the x-direction, Newton's second law gives $$F_r=ma=m\frac{dv}{dt}.$$ My book then says that $F_r=-kmv$. So thus we have $$-kv=\frac{dv}{dt},$$ from which it is trivial to find expressions for $v(t)$ and $x(t)$ by using initial conditions and integration.

The only part about the problem I don't understand is why $F_r=-kmv$. Why does the retarding force depend on the mass $m$? Since $F_r \propto v$, shouldn't we just stick a proportionality constant $k$ in there and have $F_r=-kv$?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a physical reason why mass should be included in the resistive force equation?

Comment: I suppose you could put it that way. I don't see why the resistive force should depend on the mass $m$.

Answer (score 2):

Your physical intuition is correct. A resistive force arising from motion in a viscous medium should not depend on the mass of the object. See, for example, [Stokes drag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_law) for a common model of this kind of resistive force. So it is likely that the force is defined this way to make the equation of motion look nice. If you used a different object with a different mass, $k$ would have to change accordingly.

Comment: Good answer. A good demonstration of this is to get a stack of paper coffee filters like one would use in a drip coffee maker (Mr. Coffee). Put together a stack of 5 filters and a stack of 10 filters. Drop them simultaneously from a height of about 2 meters and see what happens.  The results depend on the mass, so developing a result which "hides" the mass is, at best, misleading.  I think it's downright dishonest. The drag coefficient should be defined to be purely shape dependent.

Comment: Well, sometimes it's nice to massage definitions to get everything into the same units, or in order that a certain fixed quantity ($m$ in this case) drops out of all the equations. If the mass is fixed this can be the most natural choice, and is perhaps what the lecturer was doing here. This is no different to relativists setting $c=1$, which is usually more elegant (although unfortunately seems to convince a lot of people that $c$ is just a "conversion factor").

Answer (score 0):

Force by definition is a change in the momentum of a particle. If the the retarding force is proportional to the velocity, then the correct relationship should be as follows.
, $$\frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{d(mv)}{dt} = m\frac{dv}{dt} + v\frac{dm}{dt} = m\frac{dv}{dt}= -kv$$

Unless you forgot to point out additional information given in the problem

Comment: My text calls it the power-law approximation. It says that $\vec{F_r}=-mkv^n\frac{\vec{v}}{v}$

Comment: There you have it!

Comment: But I don't understand why this is true. Is it just a definition?

Comment: Please post the whole question.

Answer (score 0):

In a mass spring damper system it is common to transform the constants $k$ and $d$ using the expressions
 $$ k = m \omega_n^2 \\ d = 2 \zeta m \omega_n $$ where $\omega_n^2 = \frac{k}{m}$. This produces the restorative force as

$$ F_r = -k x - d \dot{x} = -m \omega_n^2 x - 2 \zeta m \omega_n \dot{x} = m \ddot{x} $$
which is simplified by dividing with $m$ to
 $$ \ddot{x} + \omega_n^2 x + 2 \zeta \omega_n \dot{x} = 0 $$

So by scaling the restorative coefficients with mass yields a simplified equation to deal with.

In your case, although not apparent in this section, the author is just using a common convention. The effect of this is that by changing the mass of the problem, the behavior remains the same, or the governing equation does not contain a mass component.